# The PE teacher made Tom run laps so hard that he was/is lying on the ground. - Tom is lying right now; which to use?

Tags: tense

Right now, Tom is lying on the ground.

**Example 1**

> The PE teacher made Tom run laps so hard that he **is** lying on the ground.

**Example 2**

> The PE teacher made Tom run laps so hard that he **was** lying on the ground.

Which example should I use to describe what Tom is doing right now?

Does the tense have to conform to the main verb? I feel that Example 2 is more correct.

Comment: I wouldn't use either. Do you mean that Tom collapsed from exhaustion and fell to the ground, or that he was so tired that he lay down for a rest?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean: he collapsed on the ground?? Or: he lay down on the ground??

The progressive or past progressive don't really work here. Or: he lay down on the ground. But if you insist on them:

**made is in the simple past and is part of an idiom** so what follows it could be expressing an idea in the present or in the past. **Your choice.**

NOW

- The teacher made Tom run laps so hard that he **is [now] lying on the ground**.

YESTERDAY

- The teacher made Tom run laps so hard that he **was lying on the ground**.